# Sublimetext 3 resolution render issue (colorful tabs) on new update

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

After updating to the latest version of sublimetext (3.0, 3143), it rendered this output:

[image]

Note: my theme is the default theme.

Is there anyway to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this problem in my case **refers to the customized theme**. I've **removed** my customized theme from "[Browse Packages]/User/Default.sublime-theme" and now this issue has been fixed and Sublimetext works fine.

Answer (score 2):

The theme you are using is referencing old images that are no longer part of the Default theme. You should probably open the command palette and run "Select Theme" to use either Default or Adaptive.

Alternatively you can use a third-party theme: https://packagecontrol.io/search/theme?sort=popularity.

Comment: Actually, Adaptive theme works fine and Default theme doesn't. I wish to have the default theme.

Comment: https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/very-colorful-tabs/31244/10?u=kingkeith